# Resolve 0x80073CF3 on Windows 10

Tags: cordova, electron, win-universal-app, electron-builder, desktop-bridge

I am developing an Electron Application (`Desktop Bridge`) that should replace an existing Cordova Application (`UWP`).

I am building the `APPX` on my macOS machine with Parallels Desktop and Windows 10 using `electron-build`.

The `APPX` can be installed without any problems, but when I try to upgrade the Cordova application with the new Electron App I get the `0x80073CF3` error code.

How can I find out what exactly causes the incompatibility?
Viewing the event logs using `eventvwr.msc` didn't help.

**Note:**
The Apps are installed via the `App Installer`.

**Edit:**
The Electron app is the successor of the Cordova app and should be able to update the Cordova app via the Microsoft Windows 10 Store.

**Edit 2:**
I just checked the architecture. Both packages do have the `ProcessorArchitecture` set to `x86`. Both have been checked by unpacking the `appxbundle` (Cordova) and `appx` (Electron) files and inspecting the `AppManifest.xml`

**Edit 3:**
The Cordova app is based on `UWP`, the Electron app is based on the `Desktop bridge`.

Comment: You can only update an existing appx install.  Removing an old-style app is up to the user.

Comment: @HansPassant I know. I want to update the existing Cordova App with an Electron App. The Cordova App is available in the Microsoft Windows 10 App store, so will the Electron App be available as an update.

Comment: 0x80073CF3 = ERROR_INSTALL_RESOLVE_DEPENDENCY_FAILED = Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, there are 3 reasons for this. I don‘t know how to resolve this issue because there is not enough details in the error message.

Comment: when you create an appx, you should see a a dependency folder. install all of them.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The Appx (Electron app) can be installed without any problem if the appxbundle (Cordova app) is not installed.